# Mock issue - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I am trying to test an API service using Moq and am getting the error message:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source').

Below is the code [Which is already working fine in the real world, the Mock is a retrospective project.]

```
models = new List<MyModel> {
    new MyModel
    {
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John Smith",
    Status = "Engineer",
    Centre = 9999
    },
    new MyModel
    {
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Jane Doe",
    Status = "Manager",
    Centre = 9999
    } };

var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyModel>>();
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(models.AsQueryable().Provider);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(models.AsQueryable().Expression);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(models.AsQueryable().ElementType);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(models.GetEnumerator());
mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<MyModel>())).Callback<MyModel>(models.Add);

mockContext = new Mock<LiveDbContext>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Add(models)).Callback<DbSet<MyModel>>(mockDbSet.Object.AddRange);

myService = new LiveService(mockContext.Object);            
var result = myService.GetStaffByCentre(9999).Result.ToList();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
```

The line that appears to be causing the error is the

```
var result = myService.GetStaffByCentre(9999).Result.ToList();
```

Comment: Attach the debugger, it will quickly show you what is throwing the exception. If you are unable to, share the stack trace so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an update, and perhaps help others in the same situation. I realised that I needed to add a Repository layer and create a mock of it in order to create and run Unit Tests.

The Mock repository used the 'models' list [see original post] as its data source which meant I could remove the need to create a 'Mock Context' object and a mock DbSet.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47603/Mock-a-Database-Repository-using-Moq) very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We don't really know what your service/SUT is doing because you haven't provided it, but I assume it performs a query on the `DbSet<MyModel>` and returns the unresolved enumerable as the `Result` member. If that is the case, the `ToList()` invocation is where the exception will be occurring, when the enumerable is resolved.

Before we go further, my first question would be can you use the in-memory database provider. Mocking EFCore is hard and [Microsoft doesn't recommend it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#unit-testing).

If there is a reason you can't use the in-memory database provider, and my assumptions are correct, this is probably occurring because you haven't set up the query provider methods such as `CreateQuery` and `Execute` which are used by LINQ extensions. Exactly which you need to mock again I can't say, I don't have enough detail.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply rgvlee. I'm new to Moq so will take time to look into your advice and post an update soon. All the best.